# What are predefined PrimeFaces keyboard layouts?

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I would like to know if there is a list of predefined PrimeFaces keyboard layouts other than `qwertyBasic`, alphabetic and so on. Layouts specific for Arabic, French Russian, German... Or should I define custom layouts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyboard.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

Available Layouts in Primefaces are `qwertyBasic`, `alphabetic`, `custom`.

For example see [Primefaces Showcase - Keyboard Live Demo](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/keyboard.xhtml)

Comment: Thanks @pudaykiran for your answer it seems the only way is to go throw custom layouts.